# Site Atlas atlas.torproject.org not find exit node

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, atlas

Lately the Atlas site is not finding the exit node I am connected, the TBB 3.5 this with javascript enabled, what should I do?

Comment: Are you able to find the exit nodes now? (The back-end of Atlas was down)

Answer (score 4):

Probably related to this bug on the torproject bugtracker: [#10486 Onionoo is down](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10486).

[Onionoo](https://www.torproject.org/projects/onionoo.html) is the backend service that Atlas queries to get information about the Tor network.